# "this was nullptr" error in C++. Linked List problems

Tags: c++, linked-list, nullptr

I'm attempting to learn about Linked Lists, as well as getting the hang of pointers.
Right now, the program I am working on is sorting names in a linked list. 
Basically, the user would enter a name, and that name gets sent between two other items in the list (if list is not empty).
I have a struct called "Node" that contains a pointer to the next node, and a piece of data (string).
Here's where I'm at. My program successfully adds a name if the head pointer is nullptr. It then sets the newNode->next to nullptr, so that I can be defined as the end of the list.

Here's that code:

```
// create a new node
Node* newNode = new Node;
Node* trail = nullptr;
Node* current = head;

// initialize the value of the new node
newNode->data = name;
// Make new node point to the previous first node
//base case 1
if (head == nullptr) {
    head = newNode;
    newNode->next = nullptr;
    return true;
}
```

The problem lies within the next section of code:

```
if (head != nullptr) {
    current = head;
    trail = current;
    current = current->next;
    while (name.at(1) > current->data.at(1)) {
        trail = current;
        current = current->next;

    }
    if (current->next = nullptr) {
        trail->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = nullptr;
    }
    if (current->next != nullptr) {
        newNode->next = current;
        trail->next = newNode;
    }

}
```

An exception gets thrown. The error message says "this was nullptr".
My question is, what does this mean? How does this error occur, and what would be the best way to fix it?
I'm sorry if this question is repetitive, but other questions like this had nothing to do with linked lists.
Thank you!

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code. If you still need help, [edit] your question to include the full error message and indicate which line causes it.

Comment: One of the problems: you have an assignment instead of comparison: `if (current->next = nullptr)`

Comment: `current = head; ... current = current->next;` If the list has only 1 node, then `current` will be null when `current->data.at(1)` is called.  That being said, you really should use `std::list` or `std::forward_list` instead of implementing a linked list manually.

Comment: Consider moving it to the code review stack, it isn't really general c++ question.

Comment: @cerkiewny This is a perfectly valid question for StackOverflow.

Comment: @cerkiewny This is 100% off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: oh sorry than, I just thought the more generic questions are supposed to be asked for normal stack overflow, not the debbuging questions, ignore my comment than :)

Comment: `CodeReview` is about working code that you want to improve. `StackOverflow` is about non-working code that you want to fix.

Comment: You haven't shown is how `head` is defined and initialised before the comment "create a new node". Your code then ASSUMES `head` is initialised to NULL. I suspect it is actually an uninitialised pointer - a common beginner trap is assuming that using `Node *head;` to define a non-static variable gives a null pointer but it actually gives an uninitialised pointer. The test `if (head == nullptr)` then gives UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR. A "this was nullptr" error can happen in such cases (some implementations give that type of error when `this` is detected as being invalid, even if it is not null).

Answer (score 1):

Where in this code do you check if the `current` is not `nullptr`?

```
    while (name.at(1) > current->data.at(1)) {
        trail = current;
        current = current->next;

    }
```

Next, please note that you have an assignment instead of comparison here:

```
    if (current->next = nullptr) {
        trail->next = newNode;
        newNode->next = nullptr;
    }
```

This `if` statement will always be false, the next statement (`if (current->next != nullptr)`) too.

Comment: I changed the while loop to contain "while (name.at(0) > current->data.at(0) && current != nullptr)". Still same result

Comment: @Apollo503: Look at what you just wrote. The boolean will be evaluated from left to right, which means that if `current` is null, it will be dereferenced *before* it is tested.